# Integration of $\iint_{\Sigma}(\vec{a}\cdot \vec{x})^2dS(x)$

Tags: integration

Let $\Sigma\subset R^3$  be the sphere of radius $R>0$ centered at the origin and let $\vec{a}=a_1\vec{e_1}+a_2\vec{e_2}+a_3\vec{e_3}$. I have to compute these integrations : 
$$\iint_{\Sigma}(\vec{a}\cdot \vec{x})^2dS(x),\qquad \iint_{\Sigma}e^{\vec{a}\cdot \vec{x}}dS(x)$$
After spending some time on this problem, I decided to look at the solution, and its states the following :

> we can make a change of coordinate system from $\vec{e_1},\vec{e_2},\vec{e_3}$ to the system $\vec{\hat{e_1}},\vec{\hat{e_2}},\vec{\hat{e_3}}$ thanks to the transformation (Houseolder matrix) :
>   $$\vec{a}=\mid a\mid \vec{\hat{e_3}}$$
>   And then the integration becomes : 
>   $$\iint_{\Sigma}(\vec{a}\cdot \vec{x})^2dS(x)=R^2\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}(\mid \vec{a}\mid R \cos \phi )^2\sin \phi d\phi d\theta )$$

And I don't understand how is it possible to make such a coordinate change and why it leads to this ? It would be really nice if someone could explain me what happened and how to deal with the general case ?

Comment: but why using Household matrix ? And why $\vec{a}=\mid \vec{a}\mid \vec{\hat{e_3}}$ ? why not $\vec{\hat{e_2}}$ or $\vec{\hat{e_1}}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the rotational invariance of the scalar product and the rotational symmetry of the sphere. The value of the integral depends only on the radius $R$ of $\Sigma$ and the length $|a|$ which is equal to the norm of the functional $x\mapsto a\cdot x$. For the calculation we may therefore assume right away that $a=|a|{\bf e}_3$ and then use spherical coordinates. No matrix computations are needed.

Comment: What do you mean by the "rotational invariance of the scalar product" ?

Comment: Ok, so $T$ is orthogonal ?

Comment: @Dicordi: If $T$ is an orthogonal map of ${\mathbb R}^3$ then $(Tx)\cdot(Ty)=x\cdot y$ for all vectors $x$ and $y$.